# F# Quotation Generating very strange compile error

Tags: f#, quotations

I am trying to work out why the following line:

```
let emailQuotation: Expr<LoginView -> string> = <@ fun (v: LoginView) -> v.Email.Text @>
```

is failing with a compile error, saying "Lookup of object on indeterminate type...". The property `ViewModel.Email` is a Xamarin Forms `Entry`, containing a `Text` property.

What more information does the compiler need, and why is it not able to interpret this expression?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is ugly. I can do this:

```
let emailQuotation = <@ fun (v: LoginView) -> let email: Entry = v.Email in email.Text @>
```

The quotation wasn't able to interpret the type of `v.Email`. I'm no expert on code quotations, so there may be a way to make the compiler pick up the type in a single expression.

Comment: Would this work? `fun (v: LoginView) -> (v.Email:Entry).Text`

Comment: I'll try. If it does work, feel free to submit an answer and I'll upvote it and mark it as the answer.

Comment: It works nicely. If you submit this as an answer, I'll mark it accordingly.